Bay window roof cleaning
My HOA wants me to paint my bay window roof.  Can I clean it?
https://imgur.com/gallery/KhQTIlA

Clean it yes.  Should you paint it is the question.  According to youtube we all know how wise and smart HOAs can be.

Your HOA, like most HOAs is a bunch of ignorant  - that's a copper roof, it's patinating to a lovely green, and painting it (or cleaning it) is a  stupid thing to do. So, be sure to use hot pink if you can't smack some sense into them.

See https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/271512/18078

@Ecnerwal is correct. Like most HOA board members, and their horrible (and often scandalous) management companies, they are completely ignorant.  That's not dirt.  That's patina, which is the natural and intended state of copper as it ages.  It's beautiful, and will get more beautiful as it ages.  You can fix a lot of things, but you just can't fix stupid.

Are there hoa prohibitions around roofing materials? If not, gently ask them to pound sand.
